# kafka cloud stream consumer condition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

When i migrated spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka to the version 3.2.5 i had many annotations that are duplicated, that i'm correcting

old consumer:

```
@StreamListener(value = KafkaStreams.INPUT_CATALOG, condition = "headers['catalog-code'] == 'CATPREST'")
public void receiveBenefitCategories(Message<ChangeNotification> changeNotification) {
    log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Nature Of Change : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", changeNotification.getPayload().getNatureOfChange());
    log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - PAYLOAD : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", changeNotification.getPayload());
}
```

new consumer:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<ChangeNotification> handleCatalogEvent() {
    return event -> {
        log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Nature Of Change : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", event.getNatureOfChange());
        log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - PAYLOAD : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", event.getItem());
    };
}
```

How can i add a conditionin the new consumer this the old `condition = "headers['catalog-code'] == 'CATPREST'"`

Comment: Have you tried using `Consumer<Message<ChangeNotification>>`, then adding an if condition within the method to check the headers of the message?